# Send Str via TCP in Python 3 to Keyence camera controller

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I need to send an ascii string command to a Keyence camera.  I wrote a python 3 code to make decisions but the command being sent is not making it.

I need to send "PW,001[CR]"  replace 1 with 2 or 3 or 4 etc to choose the program the keyence IV2 camera is running.
With putty I can send over raw TCP PW,001 and it works.
In python the socket.send wants me to encode it as a byte type object.  The keyence camera controller does nothing with it, if I print my message it will have b'PW,001' in it, I believe the Keyence controller does not know what to do with this.  The fieldnet pdf for the Keyence shows it is looking for ascii strings.  Keyence support wants me to rewrite my code in C++.  I would prefer not to completely rewrite my program just because the camera wont cooperate.  My program does config file parsing, watches for updates to that config file and decided what program to set the keyence camera to run based off of the machine updated config file.  Everything works file except for that tcp socket communication.
If there is a way to send a string via TCP without it being encoded to a byte like object, please let me know.  Thank you

EDIT  I figured it out

Solution:  Sending the commands in bytewise ascii.

This is written for Python 3.6 and is running on a windows 7 computer.  Most of the code is not included, but the TCP socket and messages sent are.
In python3 you cannot send a raw string object, it must be a bytewise object.  Converting characters to ascii with an online converter but for things like PR you will get 50 52.  You cannot just send it this way for the controller to understand it.  Also, the [CR] or end character is not something you directly convert.  In the field manual you can find a table that you can use to directly find the ascii character also, including the [CR] listed in the field manual.  This [CR] happens to be 0D.  To send this over TCP you need to send it as a byte wise object which will be formatted like the following.

b”\x50\x52\x0D”

An example for a program switch command in the field manual would be PW,001 [CR].  This is commanding the Keyence camera to switch to program 1.  To send this command in python, after creating and opening the socket you would use something like the following:
I used puppet as the name of my socket

```
Puppet.send(b”\x50\x57\x2C\x30\x30\x31\x0D”)
```

I used a variable to store my message in my code example below, but you can send the string directly.  The prefix b is for python to convert the string into a bytewise object.  The \x is the ascii encoding and the hexadecimal two-digit number immediately following is the ascii code for the specific character you are sending.  Spaces are not needed in this string or the raw command if you send it in something like putty over raw TCP connection.
Below is the TCP sending portion of my code.  If you want to try with it, just add a line to call the camera function and send it a number, like so   `camera(1)`    This will call the camera function and send it a 1 which will send a message to the Keyence camera to change to program 1.  Also change the IP address to match your Keyence camera controller if you plan on testing the function out.
For TCP  commands like this you need to setup the Keyence controller  correctly.  To setup the IP address the first time, direct connect, go to Advanced Settings->Change network settings, then save and power the controller off and back on and connect via Network connection.  Then you can set up the proper TCP settings.  You need to change Advanced Settings->Utility->FieldNet/Comm settings set to Nonprocedural command.  In I/O settings->program switching method to Panel/PC/Network.

```
import socket  #import used for communications via TCP/IP for keyence camera
TCP_IP = '192.168.1.51' #IP address of Keyence controller
TCP_PORT = 8500  #port for communications to Keyence controller
# BUFFER_SIZE = 32  #Normally 1024, the response from the camera is not used in this example

def camera(i):  #camera function to send commands to Keyence camera controller
   
    if(i=='1'):  #if camera function was called with a value of 1 then send Keyence controller commands to choose program 1
        MESSAGE = b"\x50\x57\x2C\x30\x30\x31\x0D" #byte version or PW,001[CR]
    elif(i=='2'): #if camera function was called with a value of 2 then send Keyence controller commands to choose program 2
        MESSAGE = b"\x50\x57\x2C\x30\x30\x32\x0D" #byte version or PW,002[CR]
    elif(i=='3'): #if camera function was called with a value of 3 then send Keyence controller commands to choose program 3  
        MESSAGE = b"\x50\x57\x2C\x30\x30\x33\x0D" #byte version or PW,003[CR]
    elif(i=='4'): #if camera function was called with a value of 4 then send Keyence controller commands to choose program 4  
        MESSAGE = b"\x50\x57\x2C\x30\x30\x34\x0D" #byte version or PW,004[CR]
    elif(i=='5'): #if camera function was called with a value of 5 then send Keyence controller commands to choose program 5  
        MESSAGE = b"\x50\x57\x2C\x30\x30\x35\x0D" #byte version or PW,005[CR]
    elif(i=='6'): #if camera function was called with a value of 6 then send Keyence controller commands to choose program 6
        MESSAGE = b"\x50\x57\x2C\x30\x30\x36\x0D" #byte version or PW,006[CR]  
    Keyence(MESSAGE)

def Keyence(MES):  #TCP function to send to Keyence IV series camera controller.  Socket must be created each time after closing it
    puppet = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #create the socket and call it puppet
    puppet.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))  #connect to Keyence controller
    puppet.send(MES)  #send command
    #data = puppet.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)  #receive controller's return message, we are not doing anything with it right now
    puppet.close()  #close communication to Keyence camera controller
```